# Typescript return type for adhoc return value

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Suppose that I have the following function in Typescript 2.0:

```
doSomething(): any {

    const apple: Apple = ...
    const pears: Pear[] = ...

    return {
        apple: apple,
        pears: pears
    }
}
```

I know that my function will always return an object that has an `apple` property of type `Apple` and a `pear` property of type `Pear[]`.

I don't especially want to create a new class to model this.  Is there anyway to change my return type from `any` to something more meaningful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an inline interface:

```js
doSomething(): {apple: Apple, pears: Pear[]} {

    const apple: Apple = ...
    const pears: Pear[] = ...

    return {
        apple: apple,
        pears: pears
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that there is already an accepted answer, and the answer does give you the result you want... but it does it by making more work for you.

I want you to get to the pub earlier, so my answer is this...

> [Embrace type inference](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/07/embrace-type-inference-in-typescript/)

Like this:

```
doSomething() {
```

Note that all you have to do is *remove* the type annotation.

A full working example is below. Hover over `result` in your editor and you'll see that the compiler already knows the return type without your having to type it all in.

```
class Apple {
    appleThing: string;
}

class Pear {
    pearThing: string;
}

function doSomething() {

    const apple: Apple = new Apple();
    const pears: Pear[] = [new Pear()];

    return {
        apple: apple,
        pears: pears
    }
}

var result = doSomething();
```

Answer (score 3):

in addition to @toskv answer, you can also go with a type

```
type Fruits = { apple: Apple, pears: Pear[] }

doSomething(): Fruits {

    const apple: Apple = ...
    const pears: Pear[] = ...

    return {
        apple: apple,
        pears: pears
    }
}
```

I makes sense to define a type since your are likely going to reuse it when defining a variable that will eventually be calling the function : `let fruits: Fruits; ...; fruits = doSomething()`

See in [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Apple%20%7B%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Pear%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Fruits%20%3D%20%7B%20apple%3A%20Apple%2C%20pears%3A%20Pear%5B%5D%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doSomething()%3A%20Fruits%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20apple%3A%20Apple%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20pears%3A%20Pear%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apple%3A%20apple%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pears%3A%20pears%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20fruits%3A%20Fruits%20%3D%20doSomething())